# PostgreSQL list of all tables/functions referencing a column name

Tags: postgresql, function, search, stored-procedures

I am trying to clean up a Postgres database and create some consistency in the naming conventions.

I would like generate a list of the functions where the columns exist as a checklist to work from.

I was wondering if there was an easier way than dumping the function definitions to a file and searching each column individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find tables and views containing `ColumnName`:

```
SELECT attrelid::regclass
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE attname = 'columnname'
```

To find functions which mention `ColumnName` somewhere in their code:

```
SELECT oid::regprocedure, prosrc
FROM pg_proc
WHERE prosrc ~* '\yColumnName\y'
```

(`~*` is a case-insensitive regex match, `\y` represents a word boundary.)